# How to get dynamic control checkbox in client side?

Tags: javascript, c#, checkbox, dynamic

In .net server side i was creating Dynamic controls text-box,checkbox. If i click the checkbox inside all the checkbox list controls it should get checked.
refer this image.

server side using new EventHandler i can achieve this.But i want this in clientside.

Clientside code :

```
function CheckboxHeaderClick1() {

    var chkBox = "<%=strchx1ID %>";
    if (chkBox.checked) {
        var checkboxList = "<%=strchxboxlist1ID %>"; 
        var chkBoxCount = "<%=strchxboxlist1Count %>";
        for (var i = 0; i < chkBoxCount.length; i++) {
            chkBoxCount[i].checked = true;
        }
    }
    else {
        var checkboxList = "<%=strchxboxlist1ID %>"; 
        var chkBoxCount = "<%=strchxboxlist1Count %>";
        for (var i = 0; i < chkBoxCount.length; i++) {
            chkBoxCount[i].checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

but chkBox.checked is coming undefined.From server side to client side how i can pass the checkbox control?

My code :

```
  Panel pnl1 = new Panel();
  chx1 = new CheckBox();
  chx1.ID = "chx" + fieldname;
  strchx1ID = chx1.ClientID;
  //   chx1.AutoPostBack = true;
  if (!IsPostBack)                                                                        
     chx1.Checked = true;
  // chx1.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(this.chx1_CheckedChanged);
  // chx1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "CheckboxHeaderClick1();");
  chx1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:CheckboxHeaderClick1();return false;");
  checkboxID = chx1.ID;
  chx1.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor, "#f2f2f2");                                           
  chx1.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Color, "#287082");                                                                    
  chx1.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.PaddingBottom, "6px");                                                                    
  chx1.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.FontSize, "14px!important;");                                                                    
  pnl_filters.Controls.Add(chx1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this line of code might be your problem:

```
for (var i = 0; i < chkBoxCount.length; i++)
{
    chkBoxCount[i].checked = true;     <----- Change this
    checkboxList[i].checked = true;    <----- To this
}
```